# 2000 Toyota Sienna Rear Blinker Assembly Clips Broke Off any idea how to fix clips.? and where to get clips..?

Tags: toyota, sienna

In my 2000 Toyota Sienna the rear blinker assembly clips broke off while replacing light. Any idea how to fix clips? And where to get those clips? Or, do I need to to buy whole assembly kit?

Comment: Best ask a Toyota dealer.   Have you tried EBay.

Comment: Are you talking about the socket which holds the bulb? If so, I'd suggest you go to a pic-a-part yard and find a wrecked Sienna to replace it.